Change of Variables for Multivariate Integral
I want to find the following:
$$
\int_{0}^{2}\int_{y/2}^{1}y{\rm e}^{-x^3}
\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
$$ using change of variables. I've solved
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\rm e}^{-x^2}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
$$
by changing to polar coordinates, but it doesn't look like that will be as helpful in this case.
Any ideas for a transformation I should use $?$.

You might sketch the region of integration and you can see quite clear how the change from $dxdy$ to $dydx$ affects the integral. $I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2x} ye^{-x^3}dydx$. From this you can finish it.
